# React Native - Fetch with authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I am currenty developping an app in React Native, working with an API in Python. I would like to fetch a page that requires an authentication:

[My authentication page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8dXe.png)

I'm using a fetch with a POST method :

```
 export default class WebaurionScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
  }

  state = {
      'login': '',
      'pwd': ''
   }

   componentDidMount = () => {

        AsyncStorage.getItem('login').then((value) => this.setState({ 'login': value }))
        AsyncStorage.getItem('pwd').then((value) => this.setState({ 'pwd': value }))

        return fetch('https://api-five.herokuapp.com/webaurion/login_aurion',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            login: 'mylogin',
            psw: 'mypassword',
        })
        })

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                dataSource: responseJson.NOTES,
            });
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
    }
```

But it isn't working at all ...

Could you help me out with this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "It's not working"? How are we supposed to know how your auth endpoint wants the username and password?

Comment: It should give me a page with data in JSON type

Answer (score 0):

I was playing round with this for a while, but then just went with
https://github.com/axios/axios
It should work, there is a native extension to but its not required.

Comment: I try this, it's the same result ... I'm sure if the authentication even works

Comment: Have you tied hitting the auth in postman and making sure its working before you hit the js side of things.  This helps make sure your cors is working